# VB.net to C# Equivalent of "AddressOf"

Tags: c#, vb.net, addressof

I am trying to implement this example

http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/Gridview-with-highlighted-search-results.aspx

but the only problem I am facing is the AddressOf keyword of VB.net which I am unable to convert in C#.net

can anybody help me out with this, what alternative I should use to make it work.

Thanks.

Edit: I found some searches on stackoverflow regarding similar problems but I am unable to understand them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AddressOf alternative in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280953/addressof-alternative-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just leave it out. Method groups are implicitly convertible to delegates in C#.

```
return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceWords))
```

Or even simpler(I think this requires C# 2):

```
return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, ReplaceWords);
```

But since `ReplaceWords` is so simple, I'd consider a lambda expression(Requires C# 3):

```
return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, m => "<span class=highlight>" + m + "</span>");
```

Comment: Thanks CodeInChaos, I didn't know it was that easy I think experience speaks itself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the link you posted, I'm assuming that you want this:

```
Return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ReplaceWords))
```

.. in C#?

If so you don't need the `AddressOf` keyword at all. `MatchEvaluator` is a delegate type so you can simply pass over a method (`ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, ReplaceWords)`). Alternatively, you could use an anonymous method for this to reduce the code, which makes sense as it's not being used elsewhere:

```
return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, delegate(Match m) {
    return "<span class=highlight>" + m.ToString() + "</span>";
});
```

Comment: "MatchEvaluator is an EventHandler type" MatchEvaluator is a *delegate* type. So you're using a delegate in both examples. The second code example is an anonymous function.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to translate this into:

```
new EventHandler(theMethod)
```

Comment: You can't use `new EventHandler` here. The method in his example expects a different delegate type.

Comment: True, I hadn't read over the link provided, just went with a generic(ish) option!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceWords))
```

Basically, in c# you don't need the 'addressOf' operator.  I like having it, since it makes it real clear whats up, but c# is just like that.